# Angular quickstart error

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to run tutorials from angular.io. I'm getting an error on npm start.
Here is the error. I tried to uninstal all npm, typescript, node, angular.
First part of the error:

```
npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Gia\quickstart
> tsc -p src/
    src/app/app.component.spec.ts(3,50): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(5,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(7,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(12,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(19,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(25,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(25,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(27,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(30,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
src/app/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.module.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
src/main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
```

The second part of the error:

```
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gia\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-12T15_05_48_144Z-debug.log
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "angular-quickstart",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p src/",
        "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
        "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
        "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
        "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
        "prestart": "npm run build",
        "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run serve\"",
        "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
        "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
        "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
        "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
        "pretest": "npm run build",
        "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
        "pretest:once": "npm run build",
        "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
        "angular": "^1.6.4",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "node": "0.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.0.1",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "~2.1.0",
        "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
        "tslint": "^3.15.1",
        "lodash": "^4.16.4",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~4.0.14",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
      },
      "repository": {}
    }
```

Here is an error after installing npm in the folder of application:

```
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(3,50): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(5,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.module.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
src/main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gia\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-12T15_26_01_665Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing packages. Did you try running `npm install`?

Comment: Yes. I did, installed globally.

Comment: I'm guessing you might have installed some of the dev dependency packages globally. Can you try opening command prompt/terminal, navigate to your workspace directory (where package.json is located) and run this exact command `npm install` ?

Comment: @CodeWarrior I did and I got an error again. Please, look code up.

Answer (score 0):

Those are mostly errors within the test files or missing imports within each component. You need to fix all of them before you can compile your app successfully. It doesn't seem to be a bug.

I suggest using angular-cli to create a new angular app and keep on building the tutorial components from there. Angular-cli is the official tool for creating and scaffolding angular apps.